# Update de modificação entre duas tabelas Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Preciso fazer uma integração entre dois sws da casa e preciso de ajuda.

Tenho uma tabela de integração (3ª) que receberá os dados de uma nova gerência, caso seja criada ou modificada.

Para isso, tenho uma view que traz os dados de origem e tenho uma tabela com todas as gerências cadastradas no destino para fazer comparação.

A ideia é que seja feita uma comparação entre origem e destino. Caso haja um nome de gerência na origem que não exista no destino, compara-se os ids. Caso o Id não exista, insere a informação em uma 3ª tabela. Caso o Id exista, insere esses mesmos dados na 3ª tabela. A tabela da origem pode retornar inúmeras linhas nesta comparação.

Meu problema está com a comparação. Não consigo programar de maneira que eu tenha apenas 1 linha correspondente ao ID e a Gerência nova, que será inserida na minha 3ª tabela.

Comment: Faltam dados na minha opinião mas uma Stored Procedured pode resolver o problema.

Comment: Concordo. É que toda programação que fiz está no ambiente do cliente e inacessível. Por isso só descrevi a lógica. Sim, será uma procedure, porém não consegui desenvolver a lógica dela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A ideia é que seja feita uma comparação entre origem e destino. Caso
>   haja um nome de gerência na origem que não exista no destino,
>   compara-se os ids. Caso o Id não exista, insere a informação em uma 3ª
>   tabela. Caso o Id exista, insere esses mesmos dados na 3ª tabela. A
>   tabela da origem pode retornar inúmeras linhas nesta comparação.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1 IS
  VN_NOME DESTINO.NOME%TYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR RORIGEM IN (SELECT ID,NOME FROM ORIGEM)
  LOOP
    BEGIN
      SELECT NOME INTO VN_NOME 
      FROM DESTINO WHERE ID = RORIGEM.ID;
      IF VN_NOME <> RORIGEM.NOME THEN
      END IF;
      UPDATE DESTINO SET NOME = RORIGEM.NOME
      WHERE ID = RORIGEM.ID;
    EXCEPTION
      WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        INSERT INTO TABELA3 (ID,NOME) VALUES (RORIGEM,.ID,R.ORIGEM.NOME);
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE;
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Creio que seria mais ou menos isto.

Comment: Motta, é isso mesmo. Com as alterações cabíveis a lógica funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigada.

Answer (score 0):

```
       update RDESTINO a
          set (a.nome) = 
              (select b.nome                 
                  from RORIGEM b
                where a.chave = b.chave)
          where a.documento = variavel and
          Exists (select * from RORIGEM b 
                     where (a.chave = b.chave));
```

Segue acima um exemplo de outra sintaxe, que funciona bem e é bem rápido, pode ser usado várias tabelas no Select.
Coloquei uma variável no Where para tabela de RDESTINO e filtrando por uma chave na tabela RORIGEM, se não necessitar, basta tirar a variável e manter Where Exists (...)

Espero ter ajudado